# Convert decimal to whole number - but ignoring value

Tags: excel

I know how to isolate the decimal using the TRUNC() function, as well as taking the original value and subtracting this truncated part.

And I can then multiply to get whole number.

But that only works if all my decimals are the same place.  I want something that will get me the amount after the decimal point as a whole number, regardless of how many places.

eg: 12.2 would return 2
12.21 would return 21

Comment: `=MID(A1,FIND(".",A1,1)+1,LEN(A1))` Edit: in before Scott/Matt/whoever tells me to post answer.

Comment: @findwindow that will return a string so do something like this `=--MID(A1,FIND(".",A1,1)+1,LEN(A1))` or `=VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1,1)+1,LEN(A1)))`

Comment: @ScottCraner well, if OP is gonna multiply it, it will then turn into number? Edit: but yea, yours is more foolproof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in **A1**, consider:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",A1)),A1,--MID(A1,(FIND(".",A1)+1),9999))
```

Naturally leading zeros in the output are dropped:

[image]